# Error creating Java Virtual Machine

Tags: clojure, jvm, installation

I am just trying to download all the Railscasts using this, which I found on Github https://github.com/bayan/railscast-downloader

I don't know anything about Clojure or the Java Virtual Machine, but when I try to run the railscast-download.clj script, I run into this issue on the command line

```
myname$ clj railscast-download.clj -rss http://railscasts.com/subscriptions/
cPMkaVfRUwbK1foKpHupsA/episodes.rss -type mp4
Unrecognized option: -ccp
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

What does 'Unrecognized option: -ccp' mean?  How do I fix it?

I did follow all of the previous instructions (the prerequisites), and everything up until this point seemed to work

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps put "-ccp" instead of "-cp" in your alias?

Comment: Thanks!  That error message doesn't show up anymore, but now I get Error: Could not find or load main class clojure

Comment: I don't want to do this, but I still haven't gotten anywhere.  Any thoughts?